# CasperJS via CLI: How to load external JS files?

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, casperjs

This might be a stupid question (CasperJS noob): given this example from the CasperJS docs:

```
// cow-test.js
casper.test.begin('Cow can moo', 2, function suite(test) {
    var cow = new Cow();
    test.assertEquals(cow.moo(), 'moo!');
    test.assert(cow.mowed);
    test.done();
});
```

If `Cow()` is defined in a file `\path\to\myCowClass.js`, how do I load this class when I am using CasperJS via CLI? Is this a job for the `files` config param or for `clientScripts`?

I would really love if anybody had a concise tutorial/example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take your `Cow.js` file. I assume it looks like this:

```
function Cow() {
  this.mooed = false;
}

Cow.prototype.moo = function () {
  this.mooed = true;
  return 'moo!';
}
```

This file should be a dependency of your test. Here you can:

- Inject your "class" file from the command line using the `includes` option
- Inject your "class" file from your test file using `phantom.injectJs`

**With `--includes`**

```
casperjs test --includes=/path/to/Cow.js cow-test.js
```

**With `phantom.injectJs`**

```
// cow-test.js
phantom.injectJs('/path/to/Cow.js');

casper.test.begin('Cow can moo', 2, function suite(test) {
  var cow = new Cow();
  test.assertEquals(cow.moo(), 'moo!');
  test.assert(cow.mooed);
  test.done();
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Badacadabra, thanks for the help and the concise example!